# Didn't check the radio button with data-toggle=tab when I click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my code.

```
<div class="tab-content">
<form>
     <input type="radio" href="#tab1" name="rb-membership" data-toggle="tab" checked/><label style="font-size:15px">STARTER</label>
     <input type="radio" href="#tab2" name="rb-membership" data-toggle="tab"/><label style="font-size:15px">STANDARD</label>
     <input type="radio" href="#tab3" name="rb-membership" data-toggle="tab"/><label style="font-size:15px">ENTERPRISE</label>
</form>
```

So when I click the 2nd or 3rd button. There is not checked on it but the tab is working. But when I remove the data-toggle, the checked is working but the tab is not. I need to set checked the radio button when I click it.

Comment: OP needs to include JS as well.

Comment: Original Post should include JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do just one thing remove `data-toggle="tab"` and add script

```
$('input[name="rb-membership"]').click(function () {
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Check this [Using radio buttons for tab control using bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978224/using-radio-buttons-for-tab-control-using-bootstrap) as a reference and 
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/nEWMq/139/)

Comment: There is a checked in radio button but the tabs is not working and this error added in inspect element. Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function, I'm using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: have u added bootstrap.min.js properly?

Comment: yes. <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: may b ur sequence of script is not proper..it couldn't find tab function that means bootstrap.min is not properly loaded..can u check in network whether it is loaded or not

Comment: thanks. i just moved the bootstrap.min after the jquery.min

Comment: yeah..sequence does matter :)..happy coding