# Combine Radiobuttons with Tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've tried to combine tabs with radio buttons in bootstrap v4, but I couldn't make it completely working. After failing to easily adapt that in v4, I've found the following versions for bootstrap v2:

- [Using radio buttons for tab control using bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978224/using-radio-buttons-for-tab-control-using-bootstrap)
- http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/radio-button-tabs

I tried to adapt them to v4, but I couldn't make it fully working. Either the tab does not change or the `active` state is not maintained anymore.

The general code is presented in the following:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <a id="a_rr_html" href="#html" class="btn btn-primary active" data-toggle="tab"><input type="radio" />HTML</a>
  <a id="a_rr_json" href="#json" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tab"><input type="radio" />JSON</a>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="html tab-pane active" id="html" role="tabpanel">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="json" role="tabpanel">
  </div>
</div>
```

If I remove the `data-toggle="tab"`, the radio button's active state is again maintained correctly, but obviously the tabs do not change anymore. When I created a custom function `onClick`, the bootstrap callback was not called anymore. As far as I could understand it, the combination of both prevents some bootstrap callbacks to work properly which results in the described problems.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar. Triggering the tab-pane through radio button. I got the "onclick" triggering to fire using the data-toggle attr BUT the radio button was not getting the ":checked" state. My HTML snippet is below

```html
<form id="selectForm">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item" >
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#onlyON">                            
                <input type="radio" name="distTravel" value="state" class="custom-control-input"/>
                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                <span class="custom-control-description">Travel within State</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#onlyNA"> 
                <input type="radio" name="distTravel" value="NA" class="custom-control-input"/>
                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                <span class="custom-control-description"> Travel within NA</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#world"> 
                <input type="radio" name="distTravel" value="World" class="custom-control-input" />
                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                <span class="custom-control-description"> International Travel</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="card-block tab-pane" id="onlyON" >
        "foo"
    </div>
    <div class="card-block tab-pane" id="onlyNA" >
        "boo"
    </div>
    <div class="card-block tab-pane" id="world" >
        "soo"
    </div>
</div>
```

In the end, I just came up with my own solution. I think you can incorporate this code into yours. I removed the BS4.0 data attr triggers and created a jQuery snippet to trigger hide() and show();

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aariaspapa/hcn3dpva/)